# Powershell importing one csv column in array. Contains command doesn`t work with this array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

With a powershell script
I`m importing a CSV file in an array, everything works fine.

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\test.csv" -delimiter ";"
```

But I'm not able to find easily a value in a field name PeopleID directly.
The only best method is to loop through all array line and look if the item I`m looking for exist like :

```
foreach($item in $csv)
{
    if ($csv | where {$item.PeopleID -eq 100263} | select *) { 
       #Good I found it!!!
    }
    $List.add($item.PeopleID) > $null
}
```

**Instead I decide to import only my column PeopleID directly in an array to make it faster:**

```
$csvPeople = Import-Csv "C:\test.csv" -delimiter ";" | select PeopleID
```

If you see higher, I also create an array $List that add every PeopleID in my loop.
So I have 2 arrays that are identically

The problem if I use the CONTAINS command:

```
if($csvPeople -contains 100263)
the result is   false 

if($List -contains 100263)
the result is   true
```

What can I do to have my $csvPeople array working with "contains" ?

Importing a csv column is faster than looping through result and adding it to a new array, but this array is working.

Do I'm missing somthing when I import my CSV column to have a "working" array ?

thanks

Comment: `... | select PeopleID` -> `... | select -Expand PeopleID`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `-like` not `-contains`. `-contains` is a bit finicky about how it is used. If you replace you `if` syntax with this:

`if($csvPeople -like "*100263*")`

You should be good to go. Note the wildcards on either side, I'm putting these here for you since I don't know exactly what your data looks like. You might be either able to remove them or able to change them.

Obligatory `-like` vs `-contains` article if you are interested: http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-contains

Also, @AnsgarWiechers comment above will work. I believe you will still need to wrap your number in quotes though. I don't like to do this as it requires an exact match. If you are working with the CSV in excel or elsewhere and you have whitespace or oddball line ending characters then you might not get a hit with `-contains`.

---

I just noticed this in your script above where you are doubling your efforts:

```
foreach($item in $csv) # <-- Here $item is a record in the CSV
{
    if ($csv | where {$item.PeopleID -eq 100263} | select *) { # <-- Here you are re-parsing the CSV even though you already have the data in $item 
    }
    $List.add($item.Matricule) > $null
}
```

Since I don't have the full picture of what you are trying to do I'm providing a solution that allows you to match and take action per record.

```
foreach($item in $csv)
{
    if ($item.PeopleID -eq 100263) {
      # Do something with $item here now that you matched it
    }
}
```

---

To Address your 191 users. I would take a different approach. You should be able to load a raw list of PeopleID's into a variable and then use the `-in` feature of Where to do a list-to-list comparison.

First load your target PeopleID's into a list. Assuming it is just a flat list, not a csv you could do your comparison like this:

```
$PeopleID_List = Get-Content YourList.txt
$csv | where { $_.PeopleID -in $PeopleID_List } | % { # Do something with the matched record here. Reference it with $_ }
```

This basically says for each record in the CSV I want you to check if that record's peopleID is in the $PeopleID_List. If it is, take action on that record.

Comment: Quotes are not required. PowerShell automatically does the relevant conversions, unless you need fuzzy matches. In that case the `-contains` operator won't work anyway, because it's built for exact matching.

Comment: Yes the like command is runing well, But like I said it's an array of integer (PeopleID), so I can have someone with ID = 272 and one with 2774, but if I search like '\*277*', i will find the 2774. So I need to remove the * , and if I keep the like command it's like the contains command  he doesn't found it.( if($csvPeople -like "2774"). What is weird both array seems identically, the one that I add in the loop is able to find with contains .

Comment: ok so I guess where I am perplexed is why you are changing from the where clause in the first place. Won't this solve your problem?

`$csvPeople = Import-Csv "C:\test.csv" -delimiter ";" | select PeopleID`

`$csvPeople | where { $_.PeopleID -eq "100263" }`

Comment: @Ty Savercool. On my side your "where" clause is not working. Anyway, if it was working, it just a detour because I have to find 191 people, so with this command line, I have to call the CSV 191 times. Also it doesn't give a real answer to the problem. it just a detour to try to have what I'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Ty Savercool. When you tell me to import a flat list, that's exactly what it's not. It's a CSV, That's why I import the desired column in an array. But when I search inside this array it doesn't found the PeopleID. If I loop all the CSV and create an Array adding peopleID one by one, it works. For now I call every time the CSV and it works, but I think it's slower.    $csvPeople = Import-Csv "C:\test.csv" -delimiter ";" | where-object {( $_.PeopleID -like $item.physicalDeliveryOfficeName )}. It's your solution of July 20 @ 19:21 that solve my problem, but a little bit slower I think.